# DTD ATTLIST Range of Numbers

Tags: xml, xsd, dtd

Hi is it possible to only allow a range of numbers in an ATTLIST?

I know you can have an enumeration of a set as follows:

But it is possible to have 0 - 100, without having to type all 100 numbers?  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Because DTD's don't support a type system (other than specialized notational types such as NOTATIONS, and IDREFS and NMTOKENS inside of attributes) there isn't any way to actually specify a type as numeric, much less give it a range.

Every element that can contain text is [PCDATA, or parsed character data](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#d0e2826).

If you were to use XML Schemas (XSDs vs. DTDs), there is a way to apply a [range to an integer](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#integer).

Answer (score 0):

[No, it's not](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_dtd_attributes.asp)

DTD does not distinguish data types (e.g. string vs integer) and thus has no notion of ranges.